# Installation of packages on Fedora has change from YUM -> DNF

Tags: ros, build, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an update to the installation of ROS on Fedora 4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64: the command for yum has changed to dnf.

Here is the correct command for the installation:

```
sudo dnf install collada-dom-devel python-matplotlib pcre-devel PyQwt-devel gtk2-devel tinyxml-devel PyQt4 yaml-cpp-devel python-nose pcl-devel opencv-devel ogre-devel libuuid-devel console-bridge-devel sbcl tango-icon-theme fltk-fluid cppunit-devel python-empy bzip2-devel pcl-tools python-devel mesa-libGL-devel urdfdom-devel apr-devel vtk-java pcl wxPython-devel qhull-devel numpy cmake urdfdom-headers-devel python-mock boost-devel PyOpenGL log4cxx-devel PyQt4-devel graphviz-python libtool-ltdl-devel libtheora-devel assimp libtool hddtemp vtk-python gtest-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel graphviz fltk-devel poco-devel gazebo-devel eigen3-devel python-psutil pydot mesa-libGLU-devel libcurl-devel lz4-devel libogg-devel python-pillow-qt python-netifaces opencv-python sip-devel qt-devel assimp-devel
```

I have the ability to update all the scripts and insert the correct build commands, can we initiate this in GIT?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214419/installation-of-packages-on-fedora-has-change-from-yum--%3E-dnf/) by [PacketSpike](https://answers.ros.org/users/23321/packetspike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-24**:
I've reformatted your question a bit, as it was completely unreadable before. Please use the formatting tools in the toolbar in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/404 and https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/405

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0